# How can I prove $-|x|\leq f(x)\leq |x|$

Tags: limits

> How can I prove $-|x| \leq f(x) \leq |x|$ if $f(x)=\begin{cases}x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),\quad \text{if}\quad x\not=0,\\ 0,\quad \text{if}\quad x=0\end{cases}$

I've tried all sorts of stuff. I know it's supposed to use the squeeze theorem, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to use it. I tried to use the squeeze theorem to prove the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ for all three functions is zero, but that doesn't prove that $f(x)$ is between them. I know that it is true because $\sin(1/x)$ is always between $-1$ and $1$, and multiplying that by any $x$ value will return either that $x$ value, or something less than that $x$ value. Therefore, the negative absolute value of that $x$ value will be less than or equal to that value, and the absolute value of that $x$ value will be greater than or equal to that value. How do I prove that mathematically though. There must be a way

Comment: $|\sin t| \leq 1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: To add a little to an earlier comment: if $x>0$ then you know $f(x) = x \cdot \sin(1/x) \leq \mbox{or} \geq x \cdot (\pm 1)$ and so $-|x| < f(x) \leq +|x|$

Comment: Two questions. One, what is x cdot sin(1/x)≤/≥ trying to say. I don't think I understand the way it's written

two, what happens when x<0. Meaning how do I prove the absolute value part. specifically (make the leap from the fact that xsin(1/x) is between -1x and x, to the actual absolute value inequality

Comment: If you want someone to see your comment you need to @ them (e.g. @Evanuel).  But, if $\sin(1/x) < 0$ then $f(x) \leq |x|$ and if $\sin(1/x) > 0$ then $f(x) \geq |x|$ which is why you get *either* $\leq$ *or* $\geq$.  Take it slowly and work through each case in turn -- this is a simple proof, but it's not two lines, it's more like eight as you handle all the cases (which is often the case with $|\cdot|$

Comment: @postmortes so what I think I am understanding is that -1<= sin(t) <= 1 therefore 

|sin(t)| <=1 , so far so good

Next, we know that if x>0, x*sin(1/x)<= or >=x(+/- 1) because  -1<=sin(1/x)<=1, again so far so good

But then, I am not sure what to do mathematically to get the inequalities on either side of f(x) instead of just having an either or

Comment: If $x$ and $\sin(1/x)$ are both positive then $f(x) \leq x \cdot \sin(1/x) \leq |x|$ (and the same if they're both negative).  If they have different signs then $x \cdot \sin(1/x) \leq 0$ so $f(x) = x \cdot \sin(1/x) \geq x \sin(1/x) \geq -|x|$ (since $\sin(1/x) \geq -1$).  When you put those two together you find $f(x)$ is sandwiched between $|x|$ and $-|x|$

Comment: @postmortes I think I finally get it. If they(x and sin(1/x)) are both negative or both positive, then the resulting function is positive, but since -1<=sin(1/x)<=1 it is less than or equal |x| (because x times something between -1 and 1) similarly if one is negative and the other positive, then the resultant function is negative, but since it's x times something between -1 and 1, it's still more than or equal -|x|. So thus we get -|x| <= f(x) <=0 and 0<= f(x) <= |x| which is our inequality if we exclude the 0

Comment: Yes, I think you've got it too :)  Well done!

Comment: @postmortes Thank you so very much, it has really helped my grade. Have a wonderful day

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is obviously true for $x=0$. Assume that $x\neq 0$. Then, by using the fact that $|\sin t|\leq 1$ for all real numbers $t$ we get
\begin{align*}
|f(x)| = |x\sin(1/x)| = |x|\cdot|\sin(1/x)| \leq |x|\cdot 1 = |x|.
\end{align*}
In short, we get $|f(x)| \leq |x|$ which is equivalent to the inequality you want to prove.

Comment: thank you. My issue here though is that this is still using |f(x)| rather than f(x). It makes sense, but isn't the same inequality. I understand it intuitively but not mathematically.

Comment: For any real numbers $a,b$ we have $|a| \leq |b| \iff -|b| \leq a \leq |b|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=0$, so

- $|0|\leqslant 0\leqslant |0|$

so done.

If $x\not=0$, so

- $|x|\cdot\left|\sin\frac{1}{x}\right|\leqslant |x|$ so $\left|x\sin\frac{1}{x}\right|\leqslant |x|$ implies $-|x|\leqslant x\sin \frac{1}{x}\leqslant |x|$.

so done.

Therefore, $-|x|\leqslant f(x)\leqslant |x|$.

Reference:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Definition_and_properties

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense but I get lost in two spots. Firstly, I get lost when trying to go from |f(x)| to just plain f(x). Secondly, why does the first part imply the second part. I understand it intuitively right, if x is less than or equal to a number, the negative of that number will be less than x. But how do I represent that mathermatically